# How to calculate employees reporting to a manager recursively using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary that contains mapping of employee and his/her manager like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> employees = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "A","C" },
    { "B","C" },
    { "C","F" },
    { "D","E" },
    { "E","F" },
    { "F","F" }
};
```

I want to get no of employees under each manager in the hierarchy not just their direct reports but down the hierarchy chain.
In the above dictionary the root node/ceo is listed as reporting to himself. This is the only node that is guaranteed to have this self relationship.

How can I find total no of employees reporting to each manager. Output should be

```
A - 0
B - 0
C - 2
D - 0
E - 1
F - 5
```

This is what I tried so far but it only gives counts of direct reports not all reports in the chain

```
var reports = employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.Value, (key, g) => new { employee = key, reports = g.Count() });
```

Comment: Seems like you should treat your data as an adjacency list and construct a tree, then you can walk the tree and get number of children for each node (among other things).

Comment: Your report graph has a cycle: "F" reports to "F".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in a recursion in the anonymous methods. There is one interesting approach from the functional languages: fixed-point combinator.

It looks like this:

```
public static class Combinator
{
    public static Func<TInput, TResult> Y<TInput, TResult>(Func<Func<TInput,TResult>, TInput, TResult> function)
    {
        return input => function(Y(function), input);
    }
}
```

And can be used like this:

```
    var result = employees
        .Select(employee => Combinator.Y<string, int>
            (
                (f, e) => employees.Where(x => x.Value == e && x.Value != x.Key)
                    .Aggregate(employees.Count(x => x.Value == e && x.Value != x.Key), (current, next) => current + f(next.Key))
            )
            .Invoke(employee.Key))
        .ToList();
```

Of course, it will be more useful for simler tasks, like this:

```
    var fact = Combinator.Y<int, int>((f, n) => n > 1 ? n * f(n - 1) : 1);
    var fib = Combinator.Y<uint, int>((f, n) => n > 2 ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : (n == 0 ? 0 : 1));
```

Comment: The only thing is the ToList() return a list of integers not a dictionary of employees and their counts as expected

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is virtually identical to the problem described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/08/making-the-code-read-like-the-spec.aspx).

Your spec could be written as (this is a trivial adaptation from the quoted text):

> The complete set of reports upon which an Employee depends is the transitive closure of the directly-reports-to relationship.

The post then proceeds to provide the following code to compute the transitive closure of a particular relationship:

```
static HashSet<T> TransitiveClosure<T>(
    this Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> relation,
    T item)
{
    var closure = new HashSet<T>();
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(item);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        T current = stack.Pop();
        foreach (T newItem in relation(current))
        {
            if (!closure.Contains(newItem))
            {
                closure.Add(newItem);
                stack.Push(newItem);
            }
        }
    }
    return closure;
}
```

So all that's left is to provide the code for the directly-reports-to relationship.

This can be easily computed by creating a lookup from your dictionary mapping each employee to their reports:

```
var directReportLookup = employees.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key);

Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> directReports =
    employee => directReportLookup[employee];

employees.Select(pair => new
{
    Employee = pair.Key,
    Count = directReports.TransitiveClosure(pair.Key).Count,
});
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks